# Find files and send to a temp file

Tags: vim, pipe, io-redirection, process-substitution

Vim does support a nice option to accept a file with list of files that are then opened in a Quickfix list.
Rough example, I find all files in ~ that are smaller than 1KB and pass this to Vim:

```
find ~ -type f -size -1k > /tmp/1 && vim -q /tmp/1
```

I would love to use that as zsh suffix alias:

```
alias V='> /tmp/1 && vim -q /tmp/1'
```

So that I can:

```
find ~ -type f -size -1k V
```

I use several convenience suffixes:

```
alias -g H='| head -n'
alias -g X='| xargs -d"\n"'
```

So that I can:

```
git log H 5
```

And finally I'm approaching the **Question** itself.

It makes me sad that I cannot use `mktemp` to create that temporary file. Tried all the stupid rookie shell script tricks:

```
find . | tee QL=$(mktemp) && vim -q $QL
```

I assume the solution is so simple I'd be put to shame.

At the moment I use:

```
find ... | xargs -d"\n" vim --
```

But this only fills in a list of buffers, and doesn't populate Quickfix of Location list, even though I think a command may be passed to Vim with `-c` to do so. There's a warning "Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal", and then after you quit Vim, terminal fails prints `^D` `^M` instead of `Ctrl-C` `Ctrl-D` afterwards, though this may be fixed by adding `ttyctl -f` to `.zshrc`, but in Vim itself Tab and Backspace keys misbehave in Ex mode which is very annoying.

Comment: If no luck here you may want to try the vi/vim stackexchange: http://vi.stackexchange.com/  Probably there are some vim-specific solutions to achieve what you want.

Comment: Does it have to be a postfix alias? A function named, for example, `vfind`, could do the job just as well, and could be just as easy to use.

Comment: @muru It's not just `find`, I may want to use an `ls` or `ls | grep`.

Answer (score 2):

As long as what you posted is currently working for you thus far,

```
find ~ -type f -size -1k > /tmp/1 && vim -q /tmp/1
```

And you merely want to be rid setting up the intermediary file `> /tmp/1 &&` and `/tmp/1`, see if this works for you:

```
vim -q <( find ~ -type f -size -1k )
```

### Explanation

- from your original code, you seem to be using `find` to generate desired file list with your particular criteria, then it was saved to `/tmp/1` which was merely an intermediary file just so that `vim -q filelist` could be done, because `vim -q` expects a file argument
- `<( commands...  )` is one of Bash's [process substitutions](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) , automatically runs a command and saves output to a system temp just for this purpose `/dev/fd/63` if you are curious
- `vim -q` then thinks it is getting a file, and for all intents and purposes, it actually is, so it works

### Additional tips

If you do not absolutely have to use vim's quickfix feature, but merely just want a way to quickly edit multiple files, remember you can send vim multiple file arguments (`vim file1 file2...`) so if we modify your original `find`, we could:

```
find ~ -type f -size -1k -exec vim {} +
```

Within vim

- `:args` will show in the status bar,  the argument list, like:  `file1 [file2] file3` if you are currently editing `file2`
- `:n` to navigate to next file in argument list
- `:wn` to write next meaning save this file and auto open next file
- `:prev` to go to previous file

Comment: Probably I didn't put this clear, but my intention is to be able to add a `V` after an arbitrary command, and be able to have the results of that command open in Vim's quickfix list ( or list of buffers, but this creates those keyboard mapping issues ). I'm aware of process substitution, but in this case it cannot solve the 'postfix alias' issue.

Answer (score 0):

After a long while I'm now able to answer my own question.

Top down:

```
alias -g V='| tee $(rm fifo.tmp; mkfifo fifo.tmp && echo fifo.tmp) &; vim $(< fifo.tmp ) && rm fifo.tmp'
```

That is a zsh alias that allows for:

```
find . -name TODO V
```

or

```
ls | grep asciidoc V
```

and get all the files opened as buffers in Vim.

Somehow this doesn't work without `tee`, e.g. replacing `| tee` with `>` does not open any buffers in Vim.

What we do here is we create a pipe named `fifo.tmp`, tell `tee` to redirect output from previous command to it and send this to background; meanwhile we read this pipe in a subshell and put the output as list of files to be opened by Vim.

This however doesn't work well with file names that contain whitespace.